# Javascript/NodeJS разбивка строки по формату

Tags: javascript, node.js

Допустим есть строка вида aaaa|qqqq|www|bbbb;ccc
Я хочу задать формат в виде $1|$2|$name|$4;$5
И получить объект согласно описанному выше формату с такими же ключами. Подразумевается что я сам несу ответственность за правильность введенного формата(т.е. строка должна иметь именно такой формат, который будет указан). Строка при этом может иметь больше описанных символов, в таком случае остальные символы попадают в последний элемент массива

Например:
Строка - aaaa|qqqq|www|bbbb;ccc. Формат - $1|$2|$name|$4;$5. Должно получиться: {1: 'aaaa', 2: 'qqqq': name: 'www', 4: bbbb, 5: ccc}

Строка - aaaa|qqqq|www|bbbb;ccc216asdy1%@&!^67. Формат - $1|$2|$name|$4;$5. Должно получиться: {1: 'aaaa', 2: 'qqqq': name: 'www', 4: bbbb, 5: ccc216asdy1%@&!^67}

Понятно что можно нахардкодить с помощью регекспов. Но может есть какое-то более элегантное решение либо же даже готовый плагин\модуль

Comment: как отделить разделители от ключей в Вашем формате?

Comment: split по доллару и предыдущий знак ?

Comment: @splash58 вероятно=) тогда решение очевидно

Comment: Оно, действительно, понятное. Но хотелось бы, чтобы автор хотя бы попробовал что-то написать

Comment: да, сплит по $ и за ним цифро-буквенные значения - это ключ. дальше любой разделитель(не цифро-буквенный)

Comment: Я бы посмотрел на всякие роутеры. В том же expressjs роуты описываются строками со спец-символами и компилируются в регулярки

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял разделители '|' и ';', так почему не воспользоваться split().

```js
parseString=(text)=>{
  let array=text.split('|'),lastElement;
  lastElement=array.pop().split(';');
  lastElement.forEach(e=>{
    array.push(e)
  })
  return array
}
textToArray=(text,format)=>{
  let err=false; //флаг проверяет количество переменных в формате и тексте
  let textJSON='{';
  let arrayFormat=parseString(format),
      arrayText=parseString(text);
  if(arrayFormat.length===arrayText.length){
    for(let i=0;i<arrayFormat.length;i++){
      if(i){textJSON+=','}
      textJSON+="\""+arrayFormat[i].substr(1)+"\":"+"\""+arrayText[i]+"\""
    }
  }else(err=true)
  textJSON+="}"
  return err?'Ошибка формата':JSON.parse(textJSON)
}
console.log(textToArray("aaaa|qqqq|www|bbbb;ccc",'$1|$2|$name|$4;$5'))
console.log(textToArray("aaaa|qqqq|www|bbbb;ccc216asdy1%@&!^67",'$1|$2|$name|$4;$5'))
console.log(textToArray("aaaa|^67",'$1|$2|$dfgdfgd|$name|$4;$5'))
console.log(textToArray("aaaa|qqqq|sdfsdfsd|www|bbbb;ccc216asdy1%@&!^67",'$1|$2|$dfgdfgd|$name|$4;$5'))
```

Comment: я думаю, автор хочет универсальное решение, а не для этого шаблона

Comment: @splash58 после Вашего сообщения я так тоже подумал

Comment: именно. хотелось бы универсального решения без привязки к указанным в вопросе | и ;